# How to implement pauses in a countdown loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, getelementbyid

```js
//This function is to implement sleep in js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

for (let i = 10; i != 0; i--) {
  document.getElementById("timerLabel").innerHTML = i;
    sleep(1000);
  }
```

```html
<label id="timerLabel"></label>
```

Comment: Please add more information. You only provide code, without asking any question.

Comment: You can try using setInterval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way of doing the countdown: a simple `setInterval()` will be quite enough:

```js
function countdown(n){
 const el=document.getElementById("timerLabel"),
  intv=setInterval(()=>(el.textContent=--n)||clearInterval(intv), 1000);
 el.textContent=n;
}
 
countdown(10);
```

```html
<label id="timerLabel"></label>
```